# Form won't send to mail

Tags: php, forms

I made a from in php and it seems to work. When i hit the submit button it goes to the next page and show the message has been send, except i don't receive anything in my mailbox.
Probably easy to fix but I'm pretty new at this all and tried all afternoon yesterday and running out of ideas.

```
<form class="well" method="post" action="form.php">  
<label><b>Klantgegevens</b></label>  <br>
<span class="inline span2">Winkelnaam</span><input type="text" name="winkelnaam" class="span10">  
<span class="inline span2">Straat</span><input type="text" name="straat" class="span10">  
<span class="inline span2">Huisnummer</span><input type="text" name="huisnummer" class="span10">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Verstuur</button>
</form>
```

This is the form.php

```
<?php 
$winkelnaam = $_POST["winkelnaam"];
$straat = $_POST["straat"];
$huisnummer = $_POST["huisnummer"];
mail('xxxx@xxxx.nl');  
echo 'Uw bericht is verzonden.';
?>
```

Comment: Have you set up the SMTP server in the php.ini file to use a server that allows you to connect?

Comment: you need 2 more parameters to send a mail

Comment: You should probably read up on how it works, `mail()` requires 3 parameters by default to work. EG: `mail($to,$subject,$message);` Also it will show the message as being sent, because your echo is shown regardless.

Comment: check this.ur mail function need parameters..http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide a mail subject and mail message.
See [PHP mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) documentation for more info.

`mail('xxxx@xxxx.nl', 'My subject', 'Mail message text here');`

Comment: Thanks, I'll go and check it out

Answer (score 1):

```
mail('email@address', 'Subject', 'Plain text message', $optional_headers);
```

But I recommend using a framework to send email instead of the mail() function.
Take a look at http://swiftmailer.org/